# Openfire connect to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, openfire

How to use openfire server with Microsoft SQL Server?

The connection is not working:

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://[hostname]/[database];appName=jive
```

SQL Server has instance name, how to put it here in this connection?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

First go to

1. SQL Server Configuraton Manager
2. SQL Server Network configuration
3. Protocols for [instance name]
4. Select TCP/IP and enable it
5. Select properties of it and go to IP-addresses tab
6. Last one TCP port add the number 1433 (default port for SQL Server)
7. in the connection string for openfire use the following

   jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://[hostname]:1433/[database];appName=jive

And it worked.

Comment: Thanks this helped. Enabling the TCP/IP